# LWC event.target.dataset sometimes empty, sometimes not

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm having a very strange issue where an element being clicked sometimes has it's event.target.dataset properties populated, and sometimes does not (it doesn't even have a .target it seems). Clicking the same element multiple times will sometimes work, and sometimes not, seemingly at random.

```
    handleAppointmentClick(event) {

        console.log(event);
        console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.target.dataset)));
        let selectedSlotId = event.target.dataset.id; //sometimes ends up undefined, sometimes does not.
        let selectedDay;
        let scheduleSlot;

        
        console.log('Selected Slot id: ' + selectedSlotId);
        console.log('Scheduler days');
        console.log(this._schedulerDays);
        
        for (const day of this._schedulerDays) {
            for (const slot of day.slots) {
                if (slot.id == selectedSlotId && slot.available) {
                    scheduleSlot = slot;
                    selectedDay = day;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(scheduleSlot && selectedDay) break;
        }
        if (!scheduleSlot) handleError(`Unable to locate selected slot ${selectedSlotId}. Please try again later`, this);
        else{
            this._selectedSlot = scheduleSlot;
            this._selectedDay = selectedDay;
            this.openBookingModal();
        }
    }
}
```

```
                        <template for:each={day.slots} for:item="slot">
                            <div key={slot.id} class={slot.styles} data-id={slot.id}>
                                <div class="slds-text-heading_small">
                                    {slot.startSlotLabel}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </template>
```

The results of clicking the same div 3 times. Two errors, one success

[image]

[image]

I am utterly baffled at this behavior. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inner div is the `target`, but the handler is in the outer div. Depending on where you click, a different target may be hit (parent vs child element). Use `currentTarget`, instead. The target is the element that originally fired the event, while the current target is the element with the attached handler.

Comment: Yup, that did it. I was so focused on the odd behavior I was seeing the javascript I totally overlooked that my HTML was kinda goofy with the event handler on one thing and the attribute on another. Thanks a ton, that was driving me crazy! Just needed another set of eyes.